# How can i chang Android – Boot Logo(Not boot animation)

Tags: android, mobile, hardware

I need change android TV box default boot logo image.device has root access and i tried using [change](http://www.speedfreakhorror.com/changing-android-boot-logostart-up-shutdown-animation/)  `/system/media/images`

and change initlogo.720p.rle but i am not successes

[image]

Comment: You should accept an answer if your question was answered so that in the future people will be more likely to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bootanimation.zip under android build directory **device/amlogic/$PRODUCT/** before compile process

make sure to do clean build

Comment: thanks abbaselmas for reply but i need change boot logo(which come to before boot animation)

Comment: they are also at the same directory but you can find them in your product makefile. Look for PRODUCT_COPY. Final note rle is different type of image use rle converter correctly

Answer (score 0):

Change bootanimation.zip in /system/media/bootanimation.zip

Lot of bootanimation.zip files are free to download

Comment: thanks Chakkappan for reply but i need change boot logo(which come to before boot animation)